# How can I create a dynamic excel range for a formula?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create an Excel formula that will create a sum whose range is based on the contents of a different cell.  So for example I have the following data:

[image: Example data]

The "Yes's" are based on criteria from another part of the Excel sheet, and will not always be in the same places.  I want to be able to sum the values "between" the "Yes's", so in this case `C9=SUM(B1:B9)` and `C21=SUM(B10:B21)`.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why does one include the "Yes" row and the other not?

Comment: "Yes" is telling me that there is a corresponding value in another sheet, and it's between these values that I need to count instances another element.

Comment: Yes, but you are not including row(10) in the first but including row(21) in the second as the last row.  I assumed in my answer that the "Yes" should actually be in the row under the last value to be summed.

Comment: Yeah, row 21 should not be included in the second summation.  This is just an example, the values could continue on

Comment: Then my formula will work for you.

Comment: Please remember to mark as correct if it does work by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner.  Looks like it will work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this formula in C1:

```
=IF(A2="Yes",SUM($B$1:INDEX(B:B,ROW()))-SUM($C$1:INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1)),"")
```

Then copy down.

[image: ![enter image description here]